Can I store flour that is already mixed with the dry ingredients & butter
I have a flour that is already mixed with sugar, salt, baking powder and butter. Can I store it the freezer or I must finalise the baking today?

Sugar, salt, baking powder should all be fine. Unless your butter is dried (e.g. butter powder), you'll probably want to keep it refrigerated

You could certainly store it in the fridge for a day or so. This is common with cookie dough which actually becomes easier to shape after chilling. Just use an airtight container to prevent the mix from absorbing any unwanted odors.
The freezer would work too, and it will last for quite a while. But depending on the size and shape of your unspecified proto baked good, defrosting could take a long time. I recommend dividing and shaping the dough before freezing (e.g. roll out a pie crust, proof and shape bread rolls, scoop balls of cookie dough).
